# Moving through text file c++

Tags: c++, file, text, operation

I'm trying to save numbers from first txt file to second one in reversed order.
To be clear, inside 1st txt I have typed numbers from 1 to 10 (decimal notation). When I try to count them, I get 5 or 7, depending on what's between them (space or enter).

Then, another error is that inside 2nd txt program saves as much "0s" as dl's variable value is equal to instead of loaded numbers in reversed order.

I paste the whole code, because I don't know file operation rules good enough to determine which exact part could be the source of problem. Thank You in advance.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream plik1;
    plik1.open("L8_F3_Z2a.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    fstream plik2;
    plik2.open("L8_F3_Z2b.txt", ios::out);

    if(!plik1.good() || !plik2.good()) {
        cout << "file(s) invalid" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    plik1.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int dl = plik1.tellg() / sizeof(int);

    cout << "length = " << dl << endl;

    int a;
    for(int i = 0; i < dl; i++) {
        plik1.seekg((i + 1) * sizeof(int), ios::end);
        plik1 >> a;
        plik2 << a;
        cout << i + 1 << ". a = " << a << endl;
    }
    plik1.close();
    plik2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

*edit* the output is:

> length = 7
> 1. a = 0
> 2. a = 0
> 3. a = 0
> 4. a = 0
> 5. a = 0
> 6. a = 0
> 7. a = 0
>
> --------------------------------
> Process exited after 0.03841 seconds with return value 0
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Unrelated: when you have a file that's directly for reading, prefer `std::ifstream` over the more general `std::ftstream`. Not only do you not need to specify `ios::in`, but it make it a lot harder to accidentally write to the file. The same applies to writing only and `std::ofstream`

Comment: Question: does L8_F3_Z2a.txt contain text or binaty information. You're handling it as binary, but your commentary and the file name sound a lot like it contains text.

Comment: left them here because the original task was to perform that operation only inside of one txt, as you can see both surpassed me :p

Comment: The shown code appears to assume that each number in the value occupies `sizeof(int)` characters. That assumption is wrong. I don't think you actually have the right approach that must be done here.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide an example of the input and program output in your question post. Don't describe the output, just post an example!

Comment: It's literally txt wherein I typed:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: What I don't understand is this seeming fascination that teachers (and institutions it seems) have with binary file reading and writing for files that do not need such handling (simple text is all that's required).

Comment: Yeah, I have to do it line by line separately in order to optimalize memory occupation.

Comment: It sounds like you have a simple text file.  You don't need to be messing around with `sizeof` at all.

Comment: and I added binary not because I had to but because of curiosity if it changes anything. It does not.

Comment: Doing this in-place without increasing the size of the file sounds just as fun as defragmenting a full HD.

Comment: @MilesBudnek when I removed all sizeofs I got length = 29 and 29 times "0"

Comment: @drydre That makes sense if you have Windows-style line breaks between each number.  Remember, your file is a stream of _characters_.

Comment: *and I added binary not because I had to but because of curiosity if it changes anything. It does not.* Untrue. I'll probably have to write an answer to explain it, but binary files are read as-is. A DOS newline marker is two characters and if you read the file in binary mode, you'll see both characters. If you read the file in text mode, the stream compacts the two character newline into a single character so your count of characters will not match the number of bytes in the file.

Comment: @user4581301 well maybe it's because I just added opening attribute without changing file's format to .bin? I do heard that line markers make a difference but as I previously said, my way of counting doesn't show any change while adding that attribute.

Comment: for fun I played with this a bit, maybe the effort will help you. see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce2a39a9f5af5729)

Comment: @Thomas thanks a lot, I'll peruse it thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

When a file is encoded as text the binary size of the data is irrelevant.

```
int dl = plik1.tellg() / sizeof(int);
```

will get you the side of the file in integers, but the file isn't storing integers. It is storing a stream of characters. Say for example the file holds one number:

12345

which is five characters long. Assuming the file is using good ol ASCII, that's 5 bytes. When 12345 is converted to an `int` it will probably be 4 or 8 bytes and almost certainly not 5 bytes. Assuming the common 32 bit (4 byte) `int`

```
int dl = plik1.tellg() / sizeof(int);
int dl = 5 / 4;
int dl = 1;
```

Yay! It worked! But only by the grace of whatever deity or cosmic entity you worship. Or don't worship. I'm not going to judge. To show why you can't count on this, lets look at

```
123
```

this is three characters and 3 bytes, so

```
int dl = plik1.tellg() / sizeof(int);
int dl = 3 / 4;
int dl = 0;
```

Whoops.

Similarly

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

is five numbers. The file length will probably be the sum of one byte per digit and one byte per space, 9 bytes.

Where this gets weird is some systems, looking at you Windows, use a two character end of line marker, carriage return and a line feed. This means

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

will sum up to 13  bytes.

This is why you see a different size depending on whether the numbers are separated with spaces or newlines.

## Solution

The only way to find out how many numbers are in the file is to read the file, convert the contents to numbers, and count the numbers as you find them.

How to do that:

```
int num;
int count = 0;
while (plik1 >> num) // read numbers until we can't read any more
{
    count++;
}
```

From this you can determine the size of the array you need. Then you rewind the file, seek back to the beginning, allocate the array and read the file AGAIN into the array. This is dumb. File IO is painfully slow. You don't want to do it twice. You want to read the file once and store as you go without caring how many numbers are in the file.

Fortunately there are a number of tools built into C++ that do exactly that. I like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector<int> nums;
int num;
while (plik1 >> num)
{
    nums.push_back(num); 
}
```

`vector` even keeps count for you.

Next you could

```
std::reverse(nums.begin(), nums.end());
```

and write the result back out.

```
for (int num: nums)
{
    plik2 << num << ' ';
}
```

[Documentation for `std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

If your instructor has a no `vector` policy, and [unfortunately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) many do, your best bet is to write your own simple version of `vector`. There are many examples of how to do this already on Stack Overflow.

## Addendum

In binary 5 integers will likely be 20 or 40 bytes no matter how many digits are used and no separators are required.

It sounds like storing data as binary is the bees knees, right? Like it's going to be much easier.

But it's not. Different computers and different compilers use [different sizes for integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). All you are guaranteed is an `int` is at least 2 bytes and no larger than a `long`. All of the integer types could be exactly the same size at 64 bits. Blah. Worse, [not all computers store integers in the same order.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) Because it's easier to do some operations if the number is stored backwards, guess what? Often the number is stored backwards. You have to be very, very careful with binary data and establish a data protocol (search term for more on this topic: Serialization) that defines the how the data is to be interpreted by everyone.